# Develop and debug Python 3 applications in a virtual environment with Komodo IDE 8

Tags: debugging, python-3.x, komodo

I was trying to develop and debug Python 3 applications in a virtual environment with Komodo IDE.

I applied all the project settings, tried out my tests and did a lot of research using google, stackoverflow and also tried sarchiung the komodo forums for "virtual environment" oder "venv".

My impression is, that this cannot be done at the present. Or is there a way?

How can debugging in a Python3 Virtual Environment be done in the current commercial Komodo IDE version on windows?

Comment: There are other similar questions on SO but they refer to old versions and do not answer this question (python 3 & debugging & VENV)

Answer (score 0):

Debugging in a Python3 Virtual Environment does not work yet in the current Komode IDE version on windows.

My experience is, that even if the path is properly set on debug sessions in the project settings, those are ignored in the debug session and even worse, Komodo uses c:\Python27 which should not be visible in the session.

Example:

I have c:\python27 and c:\python33 on the system

My Python 3 VENV is in c:\project\demo and I added the python 3 exe from c:\project\demo\scripts\python.exe to the project settings

I also set the environment variabels PYTHONPATH and PATH to

c:\project\demo\scripts\ respectively c:\project\demo\ and c:\project\demo\mylib

Also c:\project\demo\mylib is added to the python3 search paths.

I can run my tests from a VENV from the console withpout any problem, which has exactly the mentioned configuration.

Now I open the file with the test in the Komodo project and run / debug it.

The result is that the debug session cannot import from c:\project\demo\mylib. When I print the environment in the debug session, it shows me that it is set to c:\Python27

I wonder why all those settings exist if the debug session does not use them.